# How to sequentially prompt for user input while checking and saving each subsequent input?

Tags: c#

Lets say I'm creating a person obj and prompted the user for fields sequentially:

> Enter a Name: ......

> Enter a Age: .....

> Enter a Gender: ......

After I ask to enter a name I check if the name is valid, if not I ask for ONLY the name again. If the name is valid I then ask for the age **while saving** what the user entered for the name. Same thing for age, they enter an age if invalid **only ask for the age again**, if the age was valid save it then ask for the gender.

At the end I have all the fields and break out of lets say a while loop that contained all these prompts and create the obj.

Is there a way to sequentially check and prompt and save user input in this manner? I don't want to have to use nested while loops for each prompt

//psuedocode

```
while(true) {
   Console.WriteLine("What's your name")
   
   //read input from user 

   //error check it 

   //if valid store in name in variable

  //else prompt for name again

  Console.WriteLine("Whats your age?")
  
  //prompt user

  //if valid store it in age variable

  //else prompt age again ONLY

  //etc

 
  
}
```

if I were to use a continue statement whenever I get bad data it would reprompt for all prior prompts up until that point which is redundant behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the while loop to be around each question, rather than all questions, then use the `continue` keyword when they gave an acceptable response.